# How to add decimals in \pgfplotstableread?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, pgfplotstable, decimal-number

**How to add decimals in `\pgfplotstableread`?**

The following code works without decimals...

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
label,startyear,endyear
D, 2003, 2008
E, 2008, 2011
F, 2012, 2014
G, 2013, 2017
}\events
```

...but not with decimals (where I have also added `precision=1`)...

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,precision=1]{
label,startyear,endyear
D, 2003.8, 2008.2
E, 2008.9, 2011.7
F, 2012.3, 2014.5
G, 2013.5, 2017.4
}\events
```

....in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% read in table
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
label,startyear,endyear
A, 2011, 2012
B, 2016, 2018
C, 2018, 2022
}\authors


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,precision=1]{
label,startyear,endyear
D, 2003.8, 2008.2
E, 2008.9, 2011.7
F, 2012.3, 2014.5
G, 2013.5, 2017.4
}\events


% add color columns
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set={blue!30}]{color}{\authors}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set={red!30}]{color}{\events}

% append events table to authors table
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\authors}{\events}
% sort by startyear
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key=startyear]\sortedtable\authors

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7mm]
\pgfmathsetmacro\yscale{0.3} % scaling for y-direction 
                             % -- effectively vertical distance between bars
\pgfmathsetmacro\barheight{0.25} % height of bars

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\sortedtable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\foreach [count=\i,evaluate=\i as \ylevel using \i*\yscale] \row in {0,...,\M}{
  % get entries from table row
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]0}\of\sortedtable
  \let\txt\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]1}\of\sortedtable
  \let\xstart\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]2}\of\sortedtable
  \let\xend\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]3}\of\sortedtable
  \let\barcolor\pgfplotsretval
  \xdef\TheLastY{\ylevel}
  
  \ifnum \xend=-1
    % single day entry, draw circle
    \filldraw [draw=black!99!\barcolor,fill=\barcolor] (\xstart-2000,-\ylevel)
      circle[radius=\barheight/2.5*1cm]
      node[black,right=3pt,font=\scriptsize] {\txt};
  \else
    % interval, draw a rectangle
    \fill [\barcolor] (\xstart-2000,-\ylevel-\barheight/2) rectangle
                        (\xend-2000,-\ylevel+\barheight/2);
     % add text label right of the rectangle
    \node [right,font=\scriptsize] at (\xend-2000,-\ylevel) {\txt};
  \fi
}

\draw [Stealth-Stealth] (2003-2000,0) -- (2003-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale)
                                      -- (2023-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale);

% add ticks on x-axis
\foreach \year in {2003, 2004, ..., 2022}
  \draw (\year-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale) ++(0,3pt)
     -- ++(0,-6pt) node[rotate=45,anchor=east] {\year};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use decimals, you cannot use `\ifnum` anymore, because it does not accept decimals. There should actually be no need for `precision=1`.

An easy solution would be to use `\ifdim` instead. You only would need to convert the numbers you want to compare to dimensions then, for example by adding `pt` to them.

Another solution would be to first perform a calculation with PGF/Ti*k*Z that is sure to return only integers. So you could first define `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xendsign}{sign(\xend)}` – which returns `-1` for any negative number, `1` for any positive number and `0` for zero – and then test with `\ifnum\xendsign=-1`. This test would be true for any negative number then, not only for -1. Or you could calculate something like `\pgfmathsetmacro{\xendint}{int(\xend)}` and use this for testing.

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% read in table
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
label, startyear, endyear
A, 2011, 2012
B, 2016, 2018
C, 2018, 2022
}\authors

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
label, startyear, endyear
D, 2003.8, 2008.2
E, 2008.9, 2011.7
F, 2012.3, 2014.5
G, 2013.5, 2017.4
H, 2011.5, -1       % added to test functionality
}\events

% add color columns
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set={blue!30}]{color}{\authors}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set={red!30}]{color}{\events}

% append events table to authors table
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\authors}{\events}
% sort by startyear
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key=startyear]\sortedtable\authors

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[x=7mm]
\pgfmathsetmacro\yscale{0.3} % scaling for y-direction 
                             % -- effectively vertical distance between bars
\pgfmathsetmacro\barheight{0.25} % height of bars

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\sortedtable}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \ylevel using \i*\yscale] \row in {0,...,\M} {
  % get entries from table row
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]0}\of\sortedtable
  \let\txt\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]1}\of\sortedtable
  \let\xstart\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]2}\of\sortedtable
  \let\xend\pgfplotsretval
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]3}\of\sortedtable
  \let\barcolor\pgfplotsretval
  \xdef\TheLastY{\ylevel}
  
  \ifdim\xend pt=-1pt
    % single day entry, draw circle
    \filldraw [draw=black!99!\barcolor, fill=\barcolor] (\xstart-2000,-\ylevel)
      circle[radius=\barheight/2.5*1cm]
      node[black, right=3pt, font=\scriptsize] {\txt};
  \else
    % interval, draw a rectangle
    \fill [\barcolor] (\xstart-2000,-\ylevel-\barheight/2) rectangle
                        (\xend-2000,-\ylevel+\barheight/2);
     % add text label right of the rectangle
    \node [right, font=\scriptsize] at (\xend-2000,-\ylevel) {\txt};
  \fi
}

\draw [Stealth-Stealth] (2003-2000,0) -- (2003-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale)
                                      -- (2023-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale);

% add ticks on x-axis
\foreach \year in {2003, 2004, ..., 2022}
  \draw (\year-2000,-\TheLastY-\yscale) ++(0,3pt)
     -- ++(0,-6pt) node[rotate=45,anchor=east] {\year};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output would be:

[image]

Comment: great!!! Thanks a lot @Jasper!